# define type of queue items in python

Tags: python

I have a function with a `queue.Queue` as an argument. This queue contains elements of my self defined class `PlantCommand` and should be processed by another thread.
Therefor, I defined the thread target function in the following way:

```
def run(command_queue: queue.Queue, status: PlantStatus) -> None:
```

When I now remove one item from the queue using its `get()`-function, the type of the element is not known anymore. Is there a way to define the type of the queue items? Something like

```
def run(command_queue: queue.Queue<PlantCommand>, status: PlantStatus) -> None:
```

Or can I define the item type afterwards?
I often use the auto completition and also check my code using the syntax highlighting. And in the case of missing type information, it doesn't work anymore. I.e. when I type in `_cmd.` I get no suggestions related to the `PlantCommand`-class of the items, that I put into the queue.

[image: syntax highlighting]

```
class PlantCommand():
    NO_CMD = 0
    ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL = 1
    RUN_NC_SCRIPT = 2
    ABORT = 3
    TERMINATE = 4

    _valid_commands = (NO_CMD,
                       ENABLE_REMOTE_CONTROL,
                       RUN_NC_SCRIPT,
                       ABORT,
                       TERMINATE)

    def __init__(self, command: int = NO_CMD, file: str = '') -> None:
        if command not in PlantCommand._valid_commands:
            raise ValueError('No valid command.')
        self.command = command
        self.file = file

def run(command_queue: queue.Queue, status: PlantStatus) -> None:
    logging.debug('Plant thread started.')
    # statemachine
    while True:
        try:
            _cmd = command_queue.get_nowait()
            if _cmd.command == PlantCommand.TERMINATE:
                pass
        except queue.Empty:
            # no item in queue -> continue
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use proper Python syntax for typing container items:

```
def run(command_queue: queue.Queue[int], status: PlantStatus) -> None:
    ...
```

Since you are new to the language, keep in mind that typing is *optional* and only requested by the tooling that surrounds your development stage: if you ever get to a situation where proper typing would be too complicated, you can always just ignore it altogether.

(in time: this syntax is implemented for `queue.Queue` from Python 3.9 onwards)

This is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias - although the documentation only uses examples of the built-in types, other collections defined in Python's stdlib also work that way. The full reasoning and implementation is described on PEP 585 - https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/ . Support for this even comes for free if one implements their collection classes inheriting from the appropriate abstract base classes in `collections.abc` .

Nonetheless, regardless of being able to find the proper documentation for typing something, keep in mind that Typing expressions following the `:` must be valid ("classic") Python expressions themselves. So the `<` and `>` symbos are only used as operators in the language, and never as brackets - and since the language could actually make use of the `[` and `]` for classes even before any language changes were made to support it (as  operator overloading for classes would already work since Python 2.2, and it was just a matter of defining how `[ ]`  indexing would work for classes), those were adopted.

Comment: Using `queue.Queue[PlantCommand]` did the trick. But could you tell where this is explained? In the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#queue-objects) I didn't find anythin about `Queue[<item_type>]`.

Comment: [PEP3107](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/) defines the syntax for type annotations using the square braces.